# PHP non-object error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Please help me in this code, I don't know why this is drop this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in D:\Users\Felhasznalo\Desktop\xamppa\htdocs\dart\throwMap.php on line 7

And here is my code:

```
$p = $_GET['player'];
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=dart;host=127.0.0.1', 'root', '');
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM dart WHERE player={$p}");
$query = $query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Comment: Your `prepare()` call failed. You need to configure PDO to throw exceptions, otherwise it errors silently (and causes things like this)  `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` Then work on binding `$p` correctly as a placeholder parameter.

Comment: You need to be using `$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM dart WHERE player=:player");` and `$query->execute(array(':player' => $p));`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Are you sure? If the `prepare` fails the `execute` statement should be throwing the error. I believe the OP is overwriting the prepared statement with the next line `$query = $query->execute()`. This overwrites `$query` with the boolean return value of `true` or `false` from the `execute` statement causing the error when `fetchAll()` is called on the boolean.

Comment: @War10ck Yes, the overwrite is what's actually causing the error here (maybe, unless `$p` is a string which isn't quoted) but the much bigger issue is the use of `$p` directly.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Ah, ok that part makes sense. I was a little confused by the first comment. I see what you mean now. It doesn't help to prepare a statement if you're going to inject the user input into the prepare and not the execute. That is a problem for sure. The existing problem is the overwrite though, not the prepare.

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
$query = $query->execute();
```

to just this:

```
$query->execute();
```

(You don't need to re-assign the query var)

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#example-994

Also, please use PDO bindings to protect your app from injection attacks:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM dart WHERE player=:player");
$query->execute(array(':player' => $p));
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Comment: You should expand this answer to incorporate the placeholder binding currently missing from the code. Otherwise, it remains SQL injection vulnerable and there's no value to using `prepare()/execute()`

Comment: (and I placed it back in context of the OP's variable assignments)